# Petrick's Method Implementation (Java)

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I recently started a small project using Java to implement Quine-McCluskey's algorithm for minimizing k-maps. I've managed to do everything up until a part in Petrick's Method, where I have to distribute and simplify expressions.

Good Resource on Petrick's Method (for those who aren't familiar): [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrick%27s_method)

Currently, my system outputs a neat string, like so:

```
(A+B)(A+D)(B+C)(D+E)(C+F)(E+F)(A+B)(A)(B+C)(C)
```

Another Example:

```
(K+L)(K+M)(L+N)(M+P)(N+Q)(P+Q)
```

Which would end up as:

```
KNP + KLPQ + LMNP + LMQ + KMNQ
```

My main goal is to distribute and simplify using the following of course:

- `X + XY = X`
- `XX = X`
- `X + X = X`

I can easily do this on paper, but putting it into a working function in Java has been a whole other world to me.

Even the least bit of guidance on this matter would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, what is your question? What do you need help on? Can you show your coding attempt so far? We can't be sure what you need help with unless you add more details. Keep in mind that general guidance/tips/etc are generally considered too broad, StackOverflow is for *specific* questions regarding code.

Comment: I don't know to make a system in Java to distribute and simplify expressions, so I'm asking for guidance on where to start. If there's no resources on the Internet regarding this, how am I supposed to learn or find information about the subject without getting help from others (here on stackoverflow for instance). I feel that the overall question was pretty clear. I hope you read it. Saying that "we can't be sure what you need help with" implies you speak for everyone, which can never be the case.

Comment: If you can do it in your head or on paper, you can do it in Java. Your best bet is to tokenize your input in a way that makes it more manageable/iterizable. Try looking up how to tokenize input. After that, it's as simple as writing a loop that goes through the same process you would, trying all the different ways of combining tokens to achieve a simplified result.